# XQuery - Strip out tag but leave its text

Tags: xml, text, xquery, strip-tags

How do I strip out a set of tags in XQuery but still leave its text there? For example, if I have:

```
<root>
    <childnode>This is <unwantedtag>some text</unwantedtag> that I need.</childnode>
</root>
```

How do I strip out the unwanted tag to get:

```
<root>
    <childnode>This is some text that I need.</childnode>
</root>
```

Actually, what I really want to end up with is just the text, like:

```
This is some text that I need.
```

When I do the following:

```
let $text := /root/childnode/text()
```

I get:

```
This is  that I need.
```

It's missing the `some text` part of it.

Any ideas on how to return `This is some text that I need.`?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, simplest and shortest solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it the string-value of childnode, that you are interested in (as opposed to a sequence of text nodes, or a simplified element)? You can get the string-value from [fn:string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string):

```
string(/root/childnode)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
/*/childnode//text()
```

**When this XQuery is evaluated on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
 <childnode>This is <unwantedtag>some text</unwantedtag> that I need.</childnode>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
This is some text that I need.
```

Answer (score 0):

This XQuery:

```
declare function local:copy($element as element()) {
   element {node-name($element)}
           {$element/@*,
            for $child in $element/node()
            return if ($child instance of element())
                   then local:match($child)
                   else $child
           }
};
declare function local:match($element as element()) {
   if ($element/self::unwantedtag)
   then for $child in $element/node()
        return if ($child instance of element())
               then local:match($child)
               else $child
   else local:copy($element)
};
local:copy(/*)
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <childnode>This is some text that I need.</childnode>
</root>
```